# Наследование и массив в Javascript (ES-2015+)

Tags: javascript

Никак не могу найти ответ в Инете и разобраться что вообще происходит.

Минимальный, самодостаточный и воспроизводимый пример:

```js
const FirstClass = class {
  constructor(obj) {
    this.someArray = obj.someArray;
  }
}

const SecondClass = class extends FirstClass {
  funcTest() {
    console.log(this.someArray[0]);
  }
}

const SomeClass = class {
  constructor() {
    this.someArray = [1, 2, 3];
    this.ekz = new SecondClass(this);
  }

  someFunc() {
    this.ekz.funcTest();
  }
}

let e = new SomeClass;
e.someArray = [3, 2, 1]

console.log(e.someArray); // 3,2,1
e.someFunc(); // 1 (??????)
```

Comment: `e = someClass;` должно было быть `e = new someClass;`

Comment: Это опечатка в вопросе, исправил.

Comment: Сделай [mcve], похоже сейчас все работает именно так как ты и хотел. Непонятна последовательность действий, и что именно надо проверить, чтобы воспроизвести твою ошибку

Comment: Ссылка на массив разрывается при выполнении `e.someArray = [3, 2, 1]`. Может вам все-таки стоит начать использовать инкапсуляцию?

Comment: `e.someFunc(); // 1 (??????)` потому, что `funcTest() {console.log(this.someArray[0]); }`  выводит первый элемент массива

Comment: @LieutenantJimDangle так а предполагается что должно выводить '3' ;)

Comment: @Veles Почему 3 то, когда в массиве первый элемет 1? Массив который начинается с 3 - это другой массив, в другом экземпляре другого класса. только называется так же.

Comment: @Darth я же переопределил массив e.someArray = [3, 2, 1] до того как вызвал функцию, первый элемент 3.

Comment: Вы переопределили **другой** массив.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Проблема в том, что в `e.someArray` хранится ссылка на массив.

При создании экземпляра *SomeClass*, в поле сохраняется ссылка на массив.

При присваивании:

```
e.someArray = [3, 2, 1]
```

ссылка в самом объекте меняется, но во внутреннем объекте `ekz` ссылка осталась на старый массив.

Вариантов решения несколько:

1. не изменять это свойство напрямую.
2. сохранять не отдельное поле, а полностью объект.
3. создавать `ekz` не в конструкторе, а непосредственно в функции `someFunc()`.

Например:

```js
const FirstClass = class {
  constructor(obj) {
    this.obj = obj;
  }

  get someArray() {
    return this.obj.someArray;
  }
}

const SecondClass = class extends FirstClass {
  funcTest() {
    console.log(this.someArray[0]);
  }
}

const SomeClass = class {
  constructor() {
    this.someArray = [1, 2, 3];
    this.ekz = new SecondClass(this);
  }

  someFunc() {
    this.ekz.funcTest();
  }
}

let e = new SomeClass;
e.someArray = [3, 2, 1]

console.log(e.someArray); // 3,2,1
e.someFunc(); // 1 (??????)
```

Comment: А где вариант "унаследовать SomeClass от остальных"?

Comment: @Darth, скорее всего это не нужно